# How can I see slack bot info like user id and bot id without making api call

Tags: slack, slack-api

How can I see my slack bot info like user id and bot id without making api call

Answer (score 0):

You can IDs of most objects in the Slack Web client as they are part of the links to show their details page.

### User ID / Bot ID

If you see the message of a user in a channel you can click on the user name to get his info. That link contains the User ID:

```
https://kalkoken.slack.com/team/U12345678
```

The last part (`U12345678`) is the user ID. Or if its a bot that was posting you get it's bot ID that way.

### Channel ID

The link to open a channel in the sidebar contains the channel ID. Its also displayed in the URL when you have a channel open:

```
https://kalkoken.slack.com/messages/C12345678/
```

Again the last part (`C12345678`) is the channel ID. It will start with a G for a private channel or a G for a direct message channel.

### App ID

Similar you can get the ID of an APP on Manage / Apps page. You can click on the app names to open theirs individual pages.

```
https://kalkoken.slack.com/apps/A12345678/
```

The last part (`A12345678`) in those links is the apps ID.